# Use variables in PXE config for booting CoreOS

Tags: boot, coreos

I am using PXELinux to deploy some CoreOS nodes. currently the servers all use the "default" config in tftpboot/

My boot config contains the following 
`append ... cloud-config-url=http://<server>/cloud-config.yml` ...

Are there any environment variables that are available at this point in time that I can use in the generation the URL, such as mac address?

All the servers use the same CoreOS image so I do not want to create a new PXE config for each one. But I do want them to pull down different config.yml's

This way I could just create a new file on my webserver i.e. config-01-xx-xx-xx-xx.yml for each server as per their Mac address.

The server is aware  of its BOOTIF (mac address being used to pxe boot) can this be used at all in the boot config file?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, you cannot do that with Syslinux.

Long answer:
The `Syslinux` binary that parses the `config` file does not have provisions for processing variables like MAC, IP, etc. Only the command `ipappend` is able to append to the kernel line certain IP/MAC formatted information but that is not what you want.

Pxelinux has a config file search sequence that can process MAC addresses on the file name but is really not a flexible solution.